# ReactJs Redux Uncaught Error: Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. while trying to connect App.js to reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am trying to connect my `App` to redux. While calling `this.props.initializeApp()` in `componentDidMount()` I am having the following error inside the `appReducer`'s switch:

> Uncaught Error: Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. You
> may have misspelled an action type string constant.

I just can't understand why this is happening, double checked million time the incoming parameters inside of reducer, everything seems to be perfect.

Here is my index.js code:

```
import store from './redux/redux-store';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
reportWebVitals();
```

My app-reducer:

```js
import getAuthUserDataThunk from './auth-reducer';
    
const INITIALIZED_SUCCESS = "INITIALIZED-SUCCESS";
   
let inicialState = {
  isInitialized: false
}

const appReducer = (
  state = inicialState,
  action = { type:INITIALIZED_SUCCESS }
) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case INITIALIZED_SUCCESS: {
      return {
        ...state,
        isInitialized: true
      }
    }

    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
};

export const initializedSuccess = () => (dispatch) => ({
  type: 'INITIALIZED_SUCCESS'
});

export const initializeAppThunk = () => (dispatch) => { 
  debugger;
  // await dispatch(getAuthUserDataThunk);
  // dispatch(initializedSuccess);
};

export default appReducer;
```

And my App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar/Navbar';
import DialogsContainer from './components/Dialogs/DialogsContainer';
import News from './components/News/News';
import Music from './components/Music/Music';
import Settings from './components/Settings/Settings';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import UsersContainer from './components/Users/UsersContainer';
import ProfileContainer from './components/Profile/ProfileContainer';
import HeaderContainer from './components/Header/HeaderContainer';
import Login from './components/Login/Login';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import initializeAppThunk from './redux/app-reducer';

class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    debugger;
    this.props.initializeApp();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className='app-wrapper'>
          <HeaderContainer />
          <Navbar />
          <div className='app-wrapper-content'>
            <Routes>
              <Route path='/' element={<ProfileContainer />} />
              <Route path='/profile/' element={<ProfileContainer />} />
              <Route path='/profile/:userId/' element={<ProfileContainer />} />
              <Route path='/dialogs/*' element={<DialogsContainer />} />
              <Route path='/users/' element={<UsersContainer />} />
              <Route path='/news' element={<News />} />
              <Route path='/music' element={<Music />} />
              <Route path='/settings' element={<Settings />} />
              <Route path='/login' element={<Login />} />
            </Routes>
          </div>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

//export default App;
export default connect(null, { initializeApp: initializeAppThunk })(App);
```

redux-store.js:

```
import {applyMiddleware, combineReducers, legacy_createStore as createStore} from "redux";
import profileReducer from "./profile-reducer";
import dialogsReducer from "./dialogs-reducer";
import sidebarReducer from "./sidebar-reducer";
import usersReducer from "./users-reducer";
import authReducer from "./auth-reducer";
import appReducer from "./app-reducer";
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';

let reducersBatch = combineReducers({
    profileReducer,
    dialogsReducer,
    usersReducer,
    sidebarReducer,
    authReducer,
    appReducer

});

let store = createStore(reducersBatch, applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware));
window.store = store;
export default store;
```

Comment: It seems fairly obvious, `initializeApp`, or rather `initializeAppThunk` isn't an action creator function that returns an action object, it's just a function that returns another function. Are you using any asynchronous action middleware, e.g. thunk middleware or similar? It seems not. Can you [edit] to show your store creation code? What are you trying do do in `initializeAppThunk`?

Comment: I edited my post to show my redux-store. My idea was to dispatch a thunk to check if user is logged in or not and get authentication data to display it in header.

Comment: Ok, so it appears you've the Thunk middleware going, it *should* all be ok. Can you create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?